# Know of an optimization library (e.g. implementing least squares, etc) for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mathematical-optimization

Anyone know of an equivalent to (at least part of) [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) implemented in javascript? I'm trying to fit various distributions (e.g. skew normal) to quantiles, but I've needed an optimization library before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently ported the derivative-free non-linear constrained optimization code [COBYLA2 to Java](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla), and Reinhard Oldenburg at the University of Frankfurt in his turn converted this code into Javascript. The Javascript code, together with a self explanatory test HTML file, can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/jscobyla/downloads/list).

Comment: Wow: awesome! For anyone coming from SciPy, this appears to be directly equivalent to **scipy.optimize.fmin_powell** (which, incidentally, is implemented using COBYLA2).